# How to use \include or \input (or another command?) to render dissertation chapters as research articles?

Tags: include, article, books, documentclass

I have multiple "content" file that I need to pull into two different directions for two different document classes, `book` and `article`. There is only one book file, and I am successfully pulling the "content" files into that book with `\include`. I also need to pull each individual content file into its own article file. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\include{FILEPATH from current directory/ not root}
\end{document}
```

Here's what the file I am trying to `\include` (that is already successfully showing up in my "book" document file) looks like:

```
\chapter{title}
\section{intro}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{FILE PATH from current directory}
```

Comment: just remove `\chapter` which is not defined in `article` class, and in your book you can have `\chapter{whatever}\input{the file for that chapter}`

Answer (score 1):

This is an almost shameless edited extract from @DavidCarlisle 's answer. My suggestion is to use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report` and `article` classes). The class has `\chapter` just like in `book` and `report` but with the class option `article` chapters are treated like `\section`, sections are treated like `\subsection`, etc.

```
% use one or the other of the class declarations below
\documentclass{memoir} % typeset like a book or
%\documentclass[article]{memoir}  % typeset like an article
\begin{document}
\chapter{title of chaptera}
\input{chapa}
\chapter{title of chapterb}
\input{chapb}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{FILE PATH from current directory}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have `\chapter` in an article (this is by design, to help with exactly this use case of combining articles into a book)

So remove `\chapter` from the shared file so it looks like

**chapa.tex**

```
\section{intro}
text text text...
```

then your self-standing article version is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{title of chaptera}
\maketitle
\input{chapa}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{FILE PATH from current directory}
\end{document}
```

and your book file can be

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{title of chaptera}
\input{chapa}
\chapter{title of chapterb}
\input{chapb}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{FILE PATH from current directory}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have "borrowed" much of your answer for use in my answer, with due acknowledgement. If you object I will delete it.

Comment: @PeterWilson no that's fine (I will send you my fee later:-)